# iOS: Push Notification is not working in production

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate, distribution, apple-push-notifications

I just released my first app into apple's app store and I recognised that the push notifications are not working.

I stumbled across many duplicate postings on Stackoverflow but it seems that for some of them I have not enough know how to deal with them.

**1**. My push notification server delivers the notifications (via php) to apples push service correctly - using the production server not the sandbox.

**2.** So I think the error has something to do with receiving them on the phone. Maybe something is wrong with the release certificate and the registration?

**3**. How can I debug such an issue? I considered starting my app via xCode with Build Configuration: Release - to check if the phone registers with Apple's apns. But it always says:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

But am I right with my assumption in **3** ? - that the app maybe ins't able to register in release mode?

Below you will find a part of my distribution provisioning file. But for me everything seems alright.

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>***YGJ2X89.de.gruener.war***</string>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>***YGJ2X89.*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Comment: are you sure it registers for remote notifiacations successfully? does your app call the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in the app delegate with a valid token?   or does it call the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError ?

Comment: it calls `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` isn't called bacause the app is already registered  with my 3rd party php server i think.

Answer (score 0):

Does your php server keep track of the devices registered? Is it possible to check if the device is registered with the server?

There is no way to debug it directly, but if you need to get some logs please try read the logs from the device's console in Xcode -> Organizer. If there are problems with registering the token or invalid server response it might be clear from that log.

Comment: the registration of devices on my php server is working. furthermore i get no error when I send a push notification from my server. they are just not arriving at the devices.

Answer (score 0):

> it calls didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError.
>   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken isn't called bacause
>   the app is already registered with my 3rd party php server i think

So something's going wrong in the registration itself.

what do you mean when you say  "the registration of devices on my php server is working" ?

do you get a deviceToken from your device even after calling didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError ? try logging the error info and see what the error is

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"FAILED TO REGISTER FOR PUSH NOTIFICATIONS");
    NSLog(@"%@", error.userInfo);
}
```

If the device has failed to get a device token (which is usually passed by the app to the thrid party server), it will not get push notifications, whether you have saved an older token or you are sending it successfully.

also, are you sure notifications are not disabled on your phone (or the app in settings)?